# How can I display an image over another image

Tags: css, image

I have two images one smaller and one bigger.

How can I display the one on the other one?

My code:

```
<img src="big.jpeg" class="img" id="big">
<img src="small.jpeg" class="img" id="sml">
```

Comment: you can use css3 background-image property or use position:absolute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="a1">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxx6V.jpg" id="a1">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFxC6.jpg" id="a2">
</div>

#a1
{position:relative}
#a2
{position:absolute; top:25px; left:50px;}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/5GCYL/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute`

```
div.images{
  border:solid green 4px;
  height:120px;
  width:120px;;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position:relative;
}
.images img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UcOtESEP/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use styles for **absolute positioning**. Place both images in a `div`, which is used as a container for offsetting the image positions. Then, for each image, add absolute positioning and use the `left` and `top` style attributes to position them. Also, add a `z-index` style attribute to each image. The image with the highest `z-index` attribute will be placed on top.

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <img src="big.jpeg" class="img" id="big" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0"/>
  <img src="small.jpeg" class="img" id="sml" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1"/>
</div>
```